# What are the implications of a perfect fit model?

Tags: logistic, spss, parameterization

I perform logistic regression with a relatively small dataset (N=65), using 12 parameters (11 variables, one constant, no interactions), which results in a perfectly fitting model (in SPSS). I have a few questions about this:

1. Is it correct to say that the model saturated, or is that only the case if there are less data points than parameters?
2. Is there a difference between a saturated model and an overparameterized model?
3. What should I do, if anything, with the fact that this does model result in a perfect fit? I perform this test as a robustness check, iterations of the model that leave out some of the parameters corroborate the main findings. I don't necessarily *need* coefficient estimates of this model, because I'm mostly interested in the signs and I obtained those from a previous test (same regression, but differently defined variables).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I understand the point with regards to data, but gathering additional data is not possible. So I have a follow up question. My simplest iteration of the model has two variables of interest and a constant. One of the variables is insignificant, but becomes increasingly significant when I add controls. Yet I understand the the model becomes increasingly meaningless due to overfitting. How do I deal with this?

Comment: Also, I found this paper stating that 5-9 cases for every variable can be enough. [link](http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/165/6/710.long)

Comment: *Can* be enough, but how will you ever know?  I think your perfect fit is evidence that it just wasn't in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. You've struck upon the perfect model for your data-generating process.  You can now go home and consider the problem solved.
2. You've vastly over-fit your data.

To differentiate between these, you'll need more data from the same DGP.  I'd say `(1)` is extremely unlikely, and even without knowing your model had a perfect fit, `(2)` would be likely just from knowing you've run a logistic regression with 12 variables on 65 data points.  I dislike rules-of-thumb, but I believe there's one out there that says you should have at minimum 30 data points per variable (so try it with 2-3 variables, not 12).  A lot of this depends on the context, though.

Answer (score 5):

With N = 65 you should certainly not have 11 independent variables. Even if the sample is perfectly evenly divided (32 and 33) then the rule of thumb would indicate no more than 3 independent variables.

What should you do? You shouldn't report these results as is. You should run simpler models unless you can get more data.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this rule of thumb, Peter?

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon - the OP linked to the article disputing the rule of thumb (http://aje.oxfordjournals.org/content/165/6/710.long) with some bibliography at the end.

Comment: In the shared link the simulation study concludes at the aliens that "However, systematic discounting of results, in particular statistically significant associations, from any model with 5–9 EPV does not appear to be justified."